# Select2: how to set data after init?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to set an array of data after initializing select2. So I want to make something like this:

```
var select = $('#select').select2({});
select.data([
  {id: 1, text: 'value1'},
  {id: 1, text: 'value1'}
]);
```

But I get the following error:

> Option 'data' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a  element.;

My HTML:

```
<select id="select" class="chzn-select"></select>
```

What should I use instead of a select element?

I need to set the source of items for search

Comment: What are you trying to do? `data` is for setting selected options (I'm not sure whether your syntax is correct either), a Select2 `select` can only have one selected element so you use `.select2('val', optionValue)`. If you need multiple selected items you call `.select2()` on a hidden input or a select with the `multiple` property. If want to set the source of items for search, that's a different thing. Specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to set a new array of data for my select2 widget. Maybe .data() if wrong.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to setData method.

Comment: You mean the options list? Just updating the options inside the `select` will make the select2 instance retrieve those automatically.

Comment: I need to set the source of items for search.

Comment: Was little out of time to answer, but it is basically what PSR answered and I commented above. You just update the options inside the `select` and select2 will display those.

Comment: it is not clear that you are trying to set `selected` data not `available` data, can you change your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 23):

In onload:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $('#selectId').append(
    '<option value="' + data[index].id + '">' + data[index].value1 + '</option>'
  );
});
```

Comment: I'd personally prefer `$('#selectId').append( $.map(data, function(v, i){ return $('<option>', { val: i, text: v }); }) );` but either way should work.

Comment: Drawback of your solution is programmatic setting of data is broken. Any ideas how to fix this? Btw +1 to your solution.

Answer (score 11):

Make an `<input type="hidden">` element and bind select2 to that. Using .select2 on a regular select box doesn't let you play with the data, it just mostly gives you the UI and post-selection methods.

Source:
[Select2 Documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data)

Answer (score 6):

Source: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Add item:

```
var data = {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Barn owl'
};

var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
$('#mySelect2').append(newOption).trigger('change');
```

Clear items:

```
$('#mySelect2').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Comment: I believe that clears the SELECTED item, not the actual data in the list?

Comment: Best answer! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

For v4 you'll have to destroy and reconstruct select2 with updated data. Check https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had the scenario where changing one select2 object alters the  contents of a second (parent - child groupings effectively). I used an ajax call to retrieve a new set of Json data, which was then picked up by the second select2 object. I've included the code below:

```
 $("#group").on('change', function () {
        var uri = "/Url/RetrieveNewResults";
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            data: {
                format: 'json',
                Id: $("#group :selected").val()
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#groupchild").html('');
                $("#groupchild").select2({
                    data: data,
                    theme: 'bootstrap',
                    placeholder: "Select a Type"
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error")
            }
        });
    });
```

I found that I had to include the $("#groupchild").html('') in order to clear out the previous set of data in the second select2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can rerender and trigger the select2

render select2

```
$('.select2').select2({
  placeholder: 'Slect value',
  allowClear: true
});
```

after need to change the data `data`

```
let dataChange = [
  {
    id: 0,
    text: 'enhancement'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'bug'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'duplicate'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'invalid'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'wontfix'
  }
];
```

rerender the select2

```
$('.select2').select2('destroy');
$('.select2').empty();
$('.select2').select2({
  placeholder: 'Slect value',
  allowClear: true,
  data: dataChange
});
```

trigger select2

```
$('.select2').trigger('change');
```

Hope this is the answer for you :3

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.

### 1. Extend select2

```
    Select2.prototype.setAjax = function (ajaxOptions)
                {
                    // Set the new ajax properties
                    var oAjaxOpts = this.options.get('ajax');
                    if (oAjaxOpts != undefined && oAjaxOpts != null)
                    {
                        for (var sKey in ajaxOptions)
                        {
                            oAjaxOpts[sKey] = ajaxOptions[sKey];
                        }
                    }
                    var DataAdapter = this.options.get('dataAdapter');
                    this.dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this.$element, this.options);
                }
```

### 2. Initialize as usual (for example --- yours could be different)

```
jHtmlFrag.select2({
            dropdownParent: $(oData.jDiv),
            placeholder: "Select Option",
            allowClear: true,
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax: {
                url: "",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (oResults, params)
                {
                    let page = params.page || 1;
                    // console.log(oResults, (params.page * 10));
                    return {
                        results: oResults.data,
                        pagination: {
                            more: (page * 10) < oResults.recordsFiltered
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }).val(null).trigger('change');
```

### 3. Set Ajax options dynamically when you feel like by calling the new extension func

```
jCombo.select2('setAjax', {
            url: sUrl,
            data: function (params)
            {
                let query = {
                    search: params.term,
                    type: params._type,
                    page: params.page || 1,
                }
                return query;
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const changeDataSelect = (selector, data) =>{
  let el = document.querySelector(selector), elClone = el.cloneNode(true);
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(elClone, el);
  $(selector).empty().select2({data})
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!